# Website deployment using jenkins

Tags: jenkins, msdeploy

I am trying to deploy mvc.net website using jenkins to my local IIS server, for the same I had written windows execute bath command as **"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe" "E:\Heena\Applications\mvctest\mvctest\mvctest.csproj" /T:Build;Package /p:Configuration=DEBUG /p:OutputPath="obj\DEBUG" /p:DeployIisAppPath="/Default Web Site" /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0**

and **"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package="E:\Heena\Applications\mvctest.zip" -dest:auto,computerName='server1',Username='Administrator',Password='server@2016'  -allowUntrusted=true**

now at the time of build, buil has successed but I am getting an error as
 Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:04.60

C:\Users\ADMIN.jenkins\workspace\CICD-demo>exit 0 
[CICD-demo] $ cmd /c call C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson7267586069406813972.bat

C:\Users\ADMIN.jenkins\workspace\CICD-demo>"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package="E:\Heena\Applications\mvctest.zip" -dest:auto,computerName='server1',Username='Administrator',Password='server@2016'  -allowUntrusted=true 
Info: Using ID '06889367-aab0-4054-bee5-b54c98f58119' for connections to the remote server.
Info: Adding sitemanifest (sitemanifest).
Info: Creating application (192.168.0.47/Testing/)
Info: Adding virtual path (192.168.0.47/Testing/)
**Error Code: ERROR_SITE_DOES_NOT_EXIST
More Information: Site '192.168.0.47' does not exist.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_SITE_DOES_NOT_EXIST.
Error count: 1.**

C:\Users\ADMIN.jenkins\workspace\CICD-demo>exit -1 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: OP found the answer, without sharing. Cf comment at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40381539/website-deployment-using-jenkins#comment68819103_40765442

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be because of two things:

1. See if Web Management Service is running on 8172 and if the Web Deployment Agent Service is running
2. Try passing SetParameters file (MSBUILD would create this along with a ZIP file) in your Msdeploy command.

"...PATH\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe"- verb:sync- source:package="...AppPATH\obj\Release\Package\Application.zip",
-dest:auto,ComputerName="https://RemoteServer:8172/MsDeploy.axd",username="UNAME",password="PWD",authtype="Basic",includeAcls="False" 
- verb:sync 
- disableLink:AppPoolExtension 
- disableLink:ContentExtension 
- disableLink:CertificateExtension 
- setParamFile:"...AppPATH\obj\Release\Package\Application.SetParameters.xml" -allowUntrusted'/>

Let me know if this helps!!! cheers :)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer, but there was another issue that figured-out and deployment is done

Comment: Ok @HeenaPatel so what was the issue?